# display ms word doc within web browser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-3.5

is there a way to embed ms word doc within web browser....

i won't be able to pay for activex controls...

i cant use google docs because the docs need to uploaded to google....

cannot use office interop also because of [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

so if you know...

please suggest any other way of doing this......

Answer (score 0):

You can find some useful information at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412305%28office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Richards,

Microsoft do a similar site to google docs, try this  link

http://workspace.officelive.com/en-GB/

```
Private Sub SaveAsHTML(ByRef paWord_Doc As Word.Document, ByRef ptSavePath As String)
    ' Check Word is running
    _wordUtils.CheckDoc(paWord_Doc)
    Dim filetoSave As New FileInfo(ptSavePath)
    If (Not paWord_Doc.FullName = ptSavePath) And filetoSave.Exists Then
        filetoSave.Delete()
    End If

    paWord_Doc.WebOptions.OrganizeInFolder = False
    paWord_Doc.SaveAs(CObj(ptSavePath), Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML)
End Sub
```

You could also save you Word Documents as HTML.

Regards

Iain

Comment: @lain but do i need to upload the doc to microsoft before i can view it.... like google.....please some example code would be nice...

Comment: @richards, If you could explain what you trying to do in more detail, it would help, are your word docs being generated on the fly?

Comment: @lain : no , i have the files just stored in the server...and when a user clicks on a button , i want to display it to user (read-only)... just display only....

Comment: Then add the document manually to the website, as One off job, I have also enclosed the word interop code, but I advise not use on a server.

Comment: @lain : just one question is it better than what the other guy suggested (convert word to pdf)...

Comment: @richards PDF, both ways are valid, if you have the Word PDF Generation installed, which was a Add-on in Word 2007, not sure in 2010. You could save as pdf.

Comment: you may want to take a look at this, http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a lok at Eric Whites Blog. He has a couple of posts listing how to convert WordprocessingML into HTML (and back) and also links to a CodePlex project ([OpenXML Document Viewer](http://openxmlviewer.codeplex.com/)) where the guys are using a browser plugin to do something similar. Not exactly what I was looking for, but maybe you will find it interesting:

Transforming Open XML Word-Processing Documents to XHtml parts [1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/10/12/transforming-open-xml-word-processing-documents-to-xhtml.aspx), [2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/10/21/transforming-open-xml-word-processing-documents-to-xhtml-post-2.aspx) & [3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/10/25/transforming-open-xml-word-processing-documents-to-html-post-3.aspx)

Personally, I was hoping for something like the word editor at [SkyDrive](http://skydrive.live.com/), but I realised even that was not full featured, so I am now investigating just allowing end users to open word documents, edit them and save the results back to a web server, similar to what you can do in SharePoint. Hopefully I don't need SharePoint though.